# How do you use a function in Xcode C++ to get the input file name from the user? I can not get my code to run

Tags: c++, xcode, function, io

SOLVED-FILE NAME WAS TOO LONG
I can not for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the following code. The input file is just a .txt file that has eight 4's in it separated by spaces. So, what happens when I run the code is I get an error message from Xcode where I call the function `"get_stream(in_s);"`.

This happens after I tell it the name of the file. It says "signal sigabrt" and when I continue debugging it says:

```
"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"
```

I already changed where the program gets the input file from and placed the input file there. What is funny is I believe it might run just fine on other systems, not positive, but nobody else had problems in visual studio. So it may be an Xcode thing. I have asked 3 different professors and one is working on the solution when she gets time, the other 2 gave up. I have gotten similar programs to work but they were not exactly the same and did not use a function to get the input file.[output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN2AA.png)[EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVRr2.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> // Step (1)
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void get_stream(ifstream& in_s); // added function

int main( )
{
double x;
int count = 0;
float sum = 0, avg;
        ifstream in_s; // Step (2)-B - declaration of the stream of type input

get_stream(in_s);
cout << "\t x \t\t x^2 \t\t Current Sum \n";
        cout << "\t === \t\t === \t\t ========== \n";

        while( in_s >> x) // Step (4)-Read all numbers one-by-one to the end of the file
        {
                 sum = sum + x;
                 cout << "\t " << x <<"\t\t " << pow(x,2) << "\t\t " << sum << "\n";
           count++;
        }

     avg = sum/count;

     cout << "\n \t\t The average of these " << count << " numbers is: " << avg << endl;
        in_s.close( ); // Step (5)-Close the connection (close the file)

return 0;
}

void get_stream(ifstream& in_s)
    {

char input_file[15]; // Step (2)-A

        cout << "Please input the input file name \n"; // Step (3)-A Get the file name
        cin >> input_file;

in_s.open(input_file); // Step (3)-B - connect to the input file and test

if(in_s.fail( ))
        {
cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
           exit(1); // if we couldn't open the file to read from we exit
}
}
```

Comment: Please remove the code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem (see [mcve]). You currently appear to have excess code in `main`, and if the crash really happens at the moment `get_stream` is called, is there any reason not to have an empty body for that function?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply thank you for replying. Yeah i have tried that, I end up with the same result. I have tried to redo this without putting it into a function and it works just fine. It has something to do with getting out of the function or something of that sorts, as it is successfully opening the file.